# HTML & JavaScript (jQuery) filtering using simple script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this small script I'm trying to get working on my webpage, its supposed to filter a bunch of programming videos I'm linking to by running a small and simple javascript as shown below. I want to improve it by making so that it doesen't show the result unless ALL REQUIREMENTS are met. In example if I filter on 'python' and 'easy', i only want results that fits BOTH of those requirements. I hope i made myself understood and I also do believe its a rather simple fix.. Please take a quick look at the code below and respond as fast as possible :)

http://jsfiddle.net/uNAXC/

Comment: Did not understand. Why can't you use Javascript conditional operators (&& for AND, || for OR, ~ for NOT)?

Comment: I could but Im looking for a cleaner fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first 'build' your filter, and then apply it.

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function()
{
     var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
     var filter = '';

     //For each one checked
     $('input:checked').each(function()
     {
          filter += '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
     });

     $lis.filter(filter).show();
    console.log(filter);
}).find('input:checkbox').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a string storing your selector filter, then use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/uNAXC/2/

I put a div inside so you can see the actual selector string